# Can I pass variables back up the recursion tree in java?

Tags: java, recursion, hashmap, trie

I'm trying to build a Trie Implementation in Java, which I have managed to do. The main part of the implementation is done, I have methods to add a word or to check if the structure contains a word, but i'm having issues trying to print the trie.

I'm trying to print the trie in a `.dot` format, in order to be able to create a `.pdf` file of the trie using GraphViz.

Currently, I have a `print` method for the `TrieNode` class that prints all the nodes correctly in the right format, except for the indexes. I can't seem to get the function to find the right index numbers for the node connections.

Here is a minimal working example :

`Trie` Class :

```java
package trie;

import trie.*;

public class Trie {

   private TrieNode root;

   public Trie () {
      this.root = new TrieNode();
   }

   public TrieNode getRoot() {
     return this.root;
   }

   public void add(String word) {

     this.getRoot().add(word);

   }

   public boolean contains(String word) {

      int current;
      int length = word.length();

      TrieNode crawler = this.getRoot();

      for (current = 0; current < length; current++) {
        char currentChar = word.charAt(current);
        if (!(crawler.getChildren().containsKey(currentChar))) {
          return false;
        }
        crawler = crawler.getChildren().get(currentChar);
      }

      return (crawler.isWord());
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     Trie t = new Trie();
     t.add("apples");
     t.add("bananas");
     System.out.println(t.getRoot().print(0, 1));

   }

}
```

`TrieNode` Class :

```java
package trie;

import trie.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TrieNode {

  private HashMap<Character, TrieNode> children;
  private String content;
  private boolean isWord;

  public TrieNode() {
    this.children = new HashMap<Character, TrieNode>();
    this.content = "";
    this.isWord = false;
  }

  public TrieNode(String word, Character charToAdd) {
    this.children = new HashMap<Character, TrieNode>();
    this.content = word + String.valueOf(charToAdd);
    this.isWord = true;
  }

  public String getContent() {
    return this.content;
  }

  public HashMap<Character, TrieNode> getChildren() {
    return this.children;
  }

  public boolean isWord() {
    return this.isWord;
  }

  public void makeWord() {
    this.isWord = true;
  }

  public void addChild(Character charToAdd) {
    TrieNode child = new TrieNode(this.getContent(), charToAdd);
    child.isWord = false;
    this.getChildren().put(charToAdd, child);
  }

  public void add(String word) {
    if (word.length() == 0) {
      this.makeWord();
    } else {
      char first = word.charAt(0);
      if (!(this.getChildren().containsKey(first))) {
        this.addChild(first);
      }
      this.getChildren().get(first).add(word.substring(1));
    }
  }

  public String print(int from, int to) {
    String res = "";
    if (this.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
      from = 0;
      to = to + 1;
      return "";
    } else {
      for (char c : this.getChildren().keySet()) {
        res += String.format("\t %d -> %d [label=\" %s\"]\n", from, to, c);

        res += this.getChildren().get(c).print(to, to+1);
      }
    }
    return res;
  }

}
```

The results of the execution of the `main` program gives :

```sh
     0 -> 1 [label=" a"]
     1 -> 2 [label=" p"]
     2 -> 3 [label=" p"]
     3 -> 4 [label=" l"]
     4 -> 5 [label=" e"]
     5 -> 6 [label=" s"]
     0 -> 1 [label=" b"]
     1 -> 2 [label=" a"]
     2 -> 3 [label=" n"]
     3 -> 4 [label=" a"]
     4 -> 5 [label=" n"]
     5 -> 6 [label=" a"]
     6 -> 7 [label=" s"]
```

I'm trying to get it to return :

```sh
     0 -> 1 [label=" a"]
     1 -> 2 [label=" p"]
     2 -> 3 [label=" p"]
     3 -> 4 [label=" l"]
     4 -> 5 [label=" e"]
     5 -> 6 [label=" s"]
     0 -> 7 [label=" b"]
     7 -> 8 [label=" a"]
     8 -> 9 [label=" n"]
     9 -> 10 [label=" a"]
     10 -> 11 [label=" n"]
     11 -> 12 [label=" a"]
     12 -> 13 [label=" s"]
```

The indexes should go back up to where the root index is, but I can't find a way of stopping it from resetting...

EDIT : The only variable I have to change is the `to` variable, but it seems t can't be redefined out of context

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Either have your return value be responsible for containing a composite of the information built from recursive calls or look at the Visitor design pattern.

Comment: I don't think I can use the Visitor pattern, this is a University assignment, and the rules were to not modify the global class structure

Comment: Then a composite return value is the key